# Which is correct, "you and yours" or "yourself and yours"?

Tags: personal-pronouns

What is the correct phrasal construction "Protect you and yours" or "Protect yourself and yours"? Are they both acceptable? Thank you.

Comment: The idiom is _you and yours_. Once a phrase is frozen like this, it's immune to ordinary rules like reflexivization.

Comment: Depends on the context.

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon context, either could be correct (and the other wrong).

Consider the trick for "*Fred and I*" versus "*Fred and me*", where one changes the phrase to "we" or "us", or simply omits the "*Fred and*":

- "*We want to …*" or "*I want to …*" suggests "*Fred and I want to …*"
- "*… gave it to us*" or "*… gave it to me*" suggests "*… gave it to Fred and me*"

The same thing works here if you omit "*and yours*":

- "*The bodyguard will protect you*" suggests "*The bodyguard will protect you and yours.*"
- "*Be sure to protect yourself*" suggests "*Be sure to protect yourself and yours.*"

Comment: John Lawler says that freezing of forms trumps logical patterning.